# Running two instances of Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have written some code in eclipse and I want to run it on two separate Android emulators.

How do I do this when I click "Run"?

I read online and it said I need to do AVD configuration.  What is  that and how do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks guys.  I solve this now ::blush::

Comment: But you don't get any adb.exe issues?

Answer (score 3):

you have to create two emulator and run it seperately.

in your Run Configuration. Goto -> Target -> Select manual Target. for Both Projects.

When you run the project its automatically ask the device selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can start emulator on command line / shell.

AVD is a virtual device where you can test your application. You can define a virtual device with required screen resolution and memory etc. If using eclipse you can use the Android AVD manager available in the 'Window' menu